transform DeviceArray into Array for jax
I have a .pkl file I downloaded from a public GitHub repository and when I read it using pickle.load, i.e. using
with open('filename.pkl'), 'rb') as f:     
    file_content = pickle.load(f)

I get the following error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jax._src.device_array'

From e.g. this StackOverflow question I understand this is an issue with jax versions. Specifically, the .pkl file must have been created with a jax version <0.4, while I am currently using v0.4.31.
I then proceed to create a separate conda environment installing jax=0.3.25, following @jakevdp 's answer in that StackOverflow question, and indeed I am able to load the .pkl file. Following again @jakevdp 's advice, I proceed to save the content of the file using jax.numpy.save, as follows:
jnp.save('filename.npy', file_content)

which I can then read with
file_content = jnp.load('filename.npy', allow_pickle=True)

However, the problem now is that I need to use the content of this file with a jax v0.4.31, given the constraints of my specific use case. This is a problem because I am then back to the same issue as above, namely that the DeviceArray is not recognised.
How can I convert the (many) DeviceArrays in the original file into Arrays for the newer version of jax?

Python's pickle is not portable across library versions, and in general is not a good solution for cross-version serialization. Any time you load a pickle file, you need to use the exact same versions of relevant packages that you used when the file was created.
JAX removed DeviceArray in JAX v0.4.14, so you may be able to load your pickle files by installing JAX v0.4.13 or older.
Once you've done that, I'd suggest saving your data in a more robust format: for arrays, np.save and np.savez are good options that will be stable across versions (with allow_pickle=False). These objects will load as NumPy arrays, and then can be converted back to JAX arrays using jnp.asarray.
